# Rails and Cassandra error: NoMethodError: undefined method `unpack' for :subdomain:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to create a simple app with Ruby on Rails and Cassandra database. I'm using the [cequel](https://github.com/cequel/cequel) gem and after the installation of cequel I've created 2 models. Blog and Post.

Blog.rb

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Cequel::Record
  key :subdomain, :text
  column :name, :text
  column :description, :text
end
```

Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Cequel::Record
  belongs_to :blog
  key :id, :uuid
  column :title, :text
  column :body, :text
end
```

These are the 2 migration files:

```
class CreateBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :blogs do |t|
      t.text :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.key :id
      t.key :timeuuid
      t.text :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Then I tried to run this command `rake cequel:migrate` in order to synchronize the schema of the models with the schema in the cassandra database, but I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `unpack' for :subdomain:Symbol
```

I'm working with:
Cassandra version: 2.0.11
Rails version: 4.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cequel is not designed for usage inside an ActiveRecord model.
Remove inheritance of `ActiveRecord::Base` and delete your migrations.
Then run `rake cequel:migrate` again, everything must work.